# Switch spring-webflux microservice to http/2 (netty)

Tags: netty, http2, spring-webflux, project-reactor, alpn

Is there anyone who used spring-webflux with netty (http/2)?

[Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-http2) says:

> You can enable HTTP/2 support in your Spring Boot application with the `server.http2.enabled` configuration property. This support depends on the chosen web server and the application environment, since that protocol is not supported out-of-the-box by JDK8. **Spring Boot does not support h2c, the cleartext version of the HTTP/2 protocol. So you must configure SSL first.**

The flag `server.http2.enabled` is not working for me.

I'm using:

1. JDK8
2. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.2.RELEASE
3. Netty 4.1.24.Final

Please take a look at my config:

[image: application.yml]

HTTPS works as well. 
But the protocol is still the same (http/1.1)

[image].

Is this a problem with ALPN? Should I upgrade my app to JDK10?
I will appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: what browser do you use?  I notice HTTP1.1 if I use IE, chrome supports HTTP/2, and uses it, if available.  Also: Look at the logs, with Tomcat embedded it told me I had to include native libs.

Answer (score 5):

In short, it's supported in Spring Framework 5.1. With JDK1.8, you need to use native library for ALPN support.

The quoted statement from Spring document is misleading.

Spring HTTP/2 wiki page (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/HTTP-2-support) has more up-to-date info:

> Reactor Netty
>
> As of Spring Framework 5.1 (Reactor Netty 0.8), this server supports as well HTTP/2. JDK9+ deployments will support that protocol without specific infrastructure changes.
>
> For JDK 8 environments, or for optimal runtime performance, this server also supports HTTP/2 with native libraries. To enable that, your application needs to have an additional dependency.

Here is the pom.xml that works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- Add Spring repositories -->
<!-- (you don't need this if you are using a .RELEASE version) -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Two key points:

1. it uses spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. If the release version is available, then you don't need to have the repo in the pom file.
2. it uses netty-tcnative-boringssl-static native library to support ALPN (needed for JDK1.8)

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-http2

Seems, I found the answer.
[Webflux Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-http2):

**Currently Spring WebFlux does not support HTTP/2 with Netty. There is also no support for pushing resources programmatically to the client.**

Comment: Hey this, comment seems to be a little outdated when opening the official documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Tomcat embedded is working with h2.  Jetty and undertow, too, I think.  So in effect: Every supported embedded container, but netty :-)

Comment: netty isn't really a container, but a free-standing networking library. `undertow` is using Netty for its networking, btw.

Answer (score -3):

You could place nginx in front of webflux and configure nginx to configuration line of  `listen 443 ssl http2;`